# What is the as in the sentence called, preposition or adverb clause?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, as, adverbial-phrases

> But yogurt tasted with that spoon was also rated **as** less sweet than when eaten with heavier or larger spoons.

I have been always wondering what this kind of **as** is called grammatically, e.g. adverb, adverb clause, preposition etc. If it is a preposition, does that mean there is being omitted between **as** and less since there should be a noun to come after the preposition **as** ? Or, is it an adverb clause ? How to clarify it?

Answer (score 1):

According to oxforddictionaries.com "as" in comparisons is called an adverb and refers to the extent or the degree of something.

> It tasted like grape juice but not as sweet